# Question about iterating a function in python

Tags: python, function, for-loop, return-value

I created this function using python

```
import numpy as np
p1=1/2


def qud(x,p):
    x_sqr = x**2
    x_qud = x**3
    pn=x_sqr*p
    return x_sqr ,x_qud,pn
```

I need to iterate this function multiple times , by giving the value of **pn** in the previous iteration.

I tried this without a for loop like this,

**First iteration** : `sqr1, qud1 ,pnew =  qud(2,p1)`

**Second iteration** : `sqr2, qud2 ,pnew1 =  qud(2,pnew)`

where i have used the value `pnew` which obtained from the first iteration.

**Third iteration** : `sqr3, qud3 ,pnew2 =  qud(2,pnew1)` so on.

Now i wanted to modify my code so that values are going to stored using a for loop , when the number of iterations are given .But my code didnt work.

My code as follows,

```
i=4
sqr = np.zeros(i)
qud = np.zeros(i)
p1 = np.zeros(i)
sqr[0],qud[0],p1[0] = qud(2,p1)

for j in range (1,3) :
    sqr[j],qud[j],p1[j] = qud(2,p1[j-1])
```

can any one suggest anything so that this works ?

Thank you

Comment: In what way did it not work? Did it throw an exception? Please include the exception here if so. Was it just incorrect?

Comment: @Craig That was a typo. When i did using index j too , it didnt work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pythonic way to do this is to create a generator. The generator will maintain state and you can call `next()` or use any of the many python [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice), maps, filters, etc. Here's one way to get the first four values:

```
from itertools import islice

def qud(x,p):
    x_sqr = x**2
    x_qud = x**3
    while True:
        p = x_sqr*p                        # update p
        yield x_sqr ,x_qud,p               # yield instead of return

my_iterator = qud(2,1/2)                   # create an iterator based on itial values

for values in islice(my_iterator, 0, 4):   # loop over an islice 
    print(values)
```

This will keep making values as long as you keep iterating over it.